# Is there a way to insert content controls in the cells of a table using the Word API of Office JS?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am trying to insert a table using the Word API of Office JS that also contains content controls in some of the cells.

There is the [`insertTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#word-word-range-inserttable-member(1)) function to insert a table, but it only accepts string values as its data.

I am playing with the idea of first inserting the table with empty values and then searching for the individual cells to populate them, but I'm having a hard time finding the cells after inserting the table.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the Table object that is returned by insertTable and call either its [getCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.table?view=word-js-preview#word-word-table-getcell-member(1)) or [getCellOrNullObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.table?view=word-js-preview#word-word-table-getcellornullobject-member(1)) method. You pass to the method the row and column index of the desired cell (zero-based).

Comment: Great, that helps! I did not realize that the function insertTable() also returns a Table object (kinda unintuitive, if you ask me!). Using getCell() I can get a cell's body, and in turn I can get the range object to insert a content control, so that solves my issue. Thanks!